# Magento2: Product page is very slow (compared to other page types on the website)

Tags: performance, magento2.2.2, optimization, pagespeed

I'm working on speed optimization for a Magento 2 website.
So far we did a lot of things, including:

1. Enabling all the related built-in stuff (merged/bundled js/csc/html, cache, flat tables, etc...).
2. Production mode enabled.
3. Redis, Memcached, Varnish.
4. CDN on media & static content.
5. Lazy load on most of the images.
6. Cache Warmer extension.
7. Using GTM for external scripts like virtual chat.
8. ElasticSearch
9. Pretty strong VPS.

The results are great for most of the pages (HomPage & Categories are very fast), but the client is still unhappy with the product page performance & he is right. I checked & although it's OK compared to other websites, it's still significantly slow compared to other page types on the same website.
*If it makes any difference, it's worth mentioning that this website has almost 50,000 products.

---

-- Any idea what might be the reason for that or what can we do about it?

Comment: Check is there any block on product page which is `Excluded From Cache`, May be that is creating issue for whole Product page .

Comment: Best way to resolve performance issue is to make page  profiling with blackfire/tideways/xhprof and add to question

Comment: At the Imagine conference they mentioned multiple profilers and tests in core of Magento that help test performance.  Check those out, and Blackfire is one of them.  Also you mentioned 3 cache's, and it was mentioned Varnish is the way to go for actual page cache due to an piece of the core that Redis doesn't play well with.  Redis is still viable for User Session caching.

Comment: @LazyCoder, Your suggestion was very helpful. Thanks!